# Upgraded Galaxy S III to 4.0.4, can't drag app to taskbar anymore. How can I enable dragging again?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I upgraded my Galaxy S III to Android 4.0.4 last night and now I can't drag apps to the taskbar anymore.

Is there a setting I can change to be able to drag apps to taskbar again?

Answer (score 2):

According to the User's Manual, there isn't a setting that locks the Primary Shortcuts.  So I would suggest turning the phone off and then restarting it.

Here are the instructions from the User's Manual for Adding and Removing Primary Shortcuts.  Perhaps there's a step here that you've missed.

> You can change any of your primary shortcuts with the exception of the
>   Apps shortcut. The primary shortcuts are the bottom row of app
>   shortcuts that remain static on all home screens (by default Phone,
>   Contacts, Messaging, Internet, and Apps).

- *Note: Before replacing a primary shortcut, you must first add the replacement shortcut to the Home Screen.*

> 1. Press to display the main Home screen.
> 2. Touch and hold the primary shortcut you want to replace and then drag it to an empty space on any Home screen.
> 3. Scroll through the Home screen to find the shortcut you want to add as the new primary shortcut.
> 4. Touch and hold the new shortcut and then drag it to the empty space in the row of primary shortcuts.
> 5. The new primary shortcut will now appear on all Home screens.